# Partial Differential equations/partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative, polar-coordinates

Suppose that $$f(x,y)=g(r,\theta)$$where  $$x=\cosh \theta$$ $$y=r\sinh\theta$$

Find formulas for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ entirely in terms of $r$, $\theta $, $\frac{\partial g}{\partial r} $ and $ \frac{\partial g}{\partial \theta}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight forward by differentiation :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Let $$f(x,y)=f(x(r,\theta),y(r,\theta))=g(r,\theta)$$
Now we have by the chain rule: $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}$$ and : $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}$$
Now differentiate x and y and solve the system.

Comment: so once i've differentiated x and y and i just need to plug in my answers for those and rearrange?

Comment: Yeah, that's it ☺